# Processing (too) many XML files (with TagSoup)

Tags: xml, haskell, io, lazy-evaluation, haskell-tagsoup

I have a directory with about 4500 XML (HTML5) files, and I want to create a "manifest" of their data (essentially `title` and `base/@href`).

To this end, I've been using a function to collect all the relevant file paths, opening them with readFile, sending them into a tagsoup based parser and then outputting/formatting the resultant list.

This works for a subset of the files, but eventually runs into a `openFile: resource exhausted (Too many open files)` error. After doing some reading, this isn't so surprising: I'm using `mapM parseMetaDataFile files` which opens all the handles straight away.

What I can't figure out is how to work around the problem. I've tried reading a bit about Iteratee; Can I hook that up with Tagsoup easily? Strict IO, the way I used it anyway (heh), froze my computer even though the files aren't very big (28 KB on average).

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated. I realize the approach of creating a big list might fail as well, but 4.5k elements isn't that long... Also, there should probably be less `String` and more `ByteString` everywhere.

Here's some code. I apologize for the naivety:

```
import System.FilePath
import Text.HTML.TagSoup

data MetaData = MetaData String String deriving (Show, Eq)

-- | Given HTML input, produces a MetaData structure of its essentials.
-- Should obviously account for errors, but simplified here.
readMetaData :: String -> MetaData
readMetaData input = MetaData title base
 where
  title =
    innerText $
    (takeWhile (~/= TagClose "title") . dropWhile (~/= TagOpen "title" []))
    tags
  base = fromAttrib "href" $ head $ dropWhile (~/= TagOpen "base" []) tags
  tags = parseTags input

-- | Parses MetaData from a file.
parseMetaDataFile :: FilePath -> IO MetaData
parseMetaDataFile path = fmap readMetaData $ readFile path

-- | From a given root, gets the FilePaths of the files we are interested in.
-- Not implemented here.
getHtmlFilePaths :: FilePath -> IO [FilePath]
getHtmlFilePaths root = undefined

main :: IO
main = do
  -- Will call openFile for every file, which gives too many open files.
  metas <- mapM parseMetaDataFile =<< getHtmlFilePaths

  -- Do stuff with metas, which will cause files to actually be read.
```

Comment: You'll need to think about your design, since apparently there are so many files you can neither keep all their handles open simultaneously (the lazy approach), nor open them and read them all in simultaneously (the fully strict approach). So how about processing them one file at a time, using strict IO (e.g. `Data.Text`).

Comment: I'd love to process them one file at a time! I have no idea of how to do that, though...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The quick and dirty solution:

```
parseMetaDataFile path = withFile path $ \h -> do
    res@(MetaData x y) <- fmap readMetaData $ hGetContents h
    Control.Exception.evaluate (length (x ++ y))
    return res
```

A slightly nicer solution is to write a proper `NFData` instance for `MetaData`, instead of just using evaluate.

Comment: Ah, this works because it *forces* x and y to be evaluated, which forces the file's contents to be gotten? I tried `withFile` before, but was bitten by the lazy evaluation of ... everything (hGetContents would then be called too late).

Comment: @vicvicvic: yep -- it ensures that you've actually read the portion of the file you need before you close the handle.

Comment: Just tested this solution and it works as well as I had hoped (~4 seconds to process all files). Maybe it's dirty but so is getting stuck on an IO problem in a pure language, imho :)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to keep the current design you must make sure parseMetaDataFile has consumed the entire string from readFile before returning.  When readFile reaches end-of-file the file descriptor will be closed.

Comment: Is there an obvious way of doing this? `readMetaData` never consumes the entire file; Can I "skip-consume" somehow once it has done the interesting stuff?

Comment: @vicvicvic: see my answer. there the file is just closed (by `withFile`) once you get what you want.